# Null Pointer Exception Handling Button from XML in Library Project

Tags: android, xml, nullpointerexception

I am trying to make a custom dialog in my Library Project via XML.

Here is the XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tenlogix" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/likeitb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/likeitd" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dontlikeitb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/dontliked" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/notnowb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/notnowd" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In Simple Java Class I am creating Dialog Like this:

```
final Dialog feed_back_dialog = new Dialog(mAct);

feed_back_dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
feed_back_dialog.setCancelable(true);
feed_back_dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

feed_back_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.ratedialog);


Button LikeIt = (Button) mAct.findViewById(R.id.likeitb);
Button DontLikeIt = (Button) mAct.findViewById(R.id.dontlikeitb);
Button NotNow = (Button) mAct.findViewById(R.id.notnowb);


LikeIt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    String url = "market://details?id="+mAct.getPackageName();
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    mAct.startActivity(i);
    mAct.finish();
  }
});
```

If I don't set click listener of `LikeIt` button the dialog is displayed, but when I try to set a click listener on it. It's giving me a null pointer exception.
I am unable to find a solution for this. The `LikeIt` button is null when I try to access it.
I dont have any same name resources. Please help.

The reference `mAct` is the activity from another project in which library project is being used.
Looking forward for a positive and quick response.
Thanks.

Comment: Can we see the stack trace, please?

Comment: The issue is solved it was a programmatic mistake. Mohsin helped me fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `mAct` in these lines of code with `feed_back_dialog`
As `feed_back_dialog` is your current layout

`Button LikeIt = (Button) mAct.findViewById(R.id.likeitb);
Button DontLikeIt = (Button) mAct.findViewById(R.id.dontlikeitb);
Button NotNow = (Button) mAct.findViewById(R.id.notnowb);`

It must be like this

`Button LikeIt = (Button) feed_back_dialog.findViewById(R.id.likeitb);
Button DontLikeIt = (Button) feed_back_dialog.findViewById(R.id.dontlikeitb);
Button NotNow = (Button) feed_back_dialog.findViewById(R.id.notnowb);`

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
 Button LikeIt = (Button) feed_back_dialog.findViewById(R.id.likeitb);
```

assuming the dialog layout has a button with the id likeitb

Similarly for other views

```
 Button DontLikeIt = (Button) feed_back_dialog.findViewById(R.id.dontlikeitb);
 Button NotNow = (Button) feed_back_dialog.findViewById(R.id.notnowb);
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id mentioned in the current inflated layout. So you need to use the dialog object to initialize views coz you set the content of the layout to your dialog. The views belong to the dialog

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is you can inflate the layout like this. Then with the use of the inflated view, you can get the Button controls. [I hope **mAct** is an **Activity** object]

```
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(mAct);
    View inflatedView = li.inflate(R.layout.ratedialog, null, false);

    //button initialization
    Button LikeIt = (Button) inflatedView .findViewById(R.id.likeitb);
    Button DontLikeIt = (Button) inflatedView .findViewById(R.id.dontlikeitb);
    Button NotNow = (Button) inflatedView .findViewById(R.id.notnowb);
```